# PyQt5 callback of different name being invoked on valueChanged

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want more than one callback available to an object, but defining *any* subsequent callback in an object overwrites all previous callbacks. However, the callbacks are decorated, which seems to be messing with things. How should I define object-level callbacks, so I can use self in them?

In the following example, which you can run on any computer with Python 3.x and PyQt5.11.x, a spinbox is hooked up to two valueChanged callbacks. These are called `A` and `C`. However, the second callback `C` never triggers, and a third callback `D` triggers instead. `D` should not trigger.

The callbacks print their letters and the spinbox value, so the expected output when spinning the spinbox is:

```
got A 1
got C 1
```

However, the actual output is:

```
got A 1
got D 1
```

This is wrong because the spinbox is hooked up to

```
callbackA
self.callbackC
```

I do not know why D is being called, since I don't actually reference it anywhere. However, if we remove any of the decorators from C or D they work again. What am I doing wrong?

The code in question is:

```python
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


def silenceCallbacks(*elements):
    """Silence events for the duration of a callback. Mostly skipped for this reproduction."""
    def silenceCallbacksOf(callback):
        def silencedCallback(self, *args, **kwargs):
            callback(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return silencedCallback
    return silenceCallbacksOf


@pyqtSlot(int)
@silenceCallbacks()
def callbackA(px: int):
    #correctly called
    print('got A', px)

@pyqtSlot(int) #this overwrites the last three functions
@silenceCallbacks()
def callbackB(px: int):
    #correctly not called
    print('got B', px)


class RecordingSettings(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    @silenceCallbacks()
    def callbackC(self, px: int):
        #incorrectly not called
        print('got C', px)

    @pyqtSlot(int) #this overwrites the previous pyqtSlot-decorated function
    @silenceCallbacks()
    def callbackD(self, px: int):
        #incorrectly called
        print('got D', px)


    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__()

        spin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()

        spin.valueChanged.connect(callbackA)
        spin.valueChanged.connect(self.callbackC)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(spin)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
recSettingsWindow = RecordingSettings(app)
recSettingsWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: observation: pyqtSlot only works for methods that belong to a class that inherit from QObject, in your case callbackA and callbackB does not belong to any class.

Comment: Interesting! That must be why A and B are working, since pyqtSlot is probably not doing anything in their case and thus not causing the issue.

Comment: Exactly, my observation goes there.

Answer (score 0):

So, the fix for this turns out to be simple if non-obvious. After a good 10 hours of trouble:

You change:

```
@pyqtSlot(int)
```

to:

```
@pyqtSlot(int, name="unique_name_here")
```

and it works.

I recommend using the name of the function being decorated as the unique name.

Comment: Note: This comment originally contained some profanity, which was because in this case it was absolutely deserved. This is the right time for it, because PyQT5 absolutely deserves to die horribly for the particular sin that prompted this question. However, I am willing leave Ollie's edit in as it has been 3 years now and I've stopped working with the technology.